# The simple way to multiple left join while selecting exclude redundant fields

Tags: mysql

```
Input 

t1
a  b  c 

t2 
a  d  e

t3 
a  f  g
```

**Expected multiple left join**

```
a b c d e f g
```

**Trying**

```
select t1.*, t2.d,t2.e,t3.f,t3.g
from t1 left join (t2, t3) 
on (
t1.a=t2.a
and t1.a= t3.a )
```

It is not convenient to get the result if there are more than 10 fields to join.

If I run the codes as follows, it returns redundant fields `a`

```
select * 
from t1 left join (t2, t3) 
on (
t1.a=t2.a
and t1.a= t3.a )


a b c a(1) d e a(2) f g
```

Comment: What are the names of the columns of each input table, and of the resulting table?

Comment: It would be easy to produce a vertical result set, with each value in a separate line. If you want to produce a horizontal result set you'll need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @TheImpaler t1 is a, b, c , t2 is a,d,e , t3 is a,f,g

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, and `c` the column names or the values?

Comment: Sorry, no free lunch here. You must code it up the hard way.

Comment: @TheImpaler the column names

Comment: Yes, you need to type each column name, as in your first solution. The SQL Standard doesn't offer any syntax to perform "column set arithmetic". This has been asked before many, many times.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the USING clause instead of ON, it does not return redundant fields.

```
select * 
from t1 
left join t2 using (a)
left join t3 using (a);
```

This will return:
a b c d e f g